# Why Kotlin can not override List<*> operator method?

Tags: kotlin

Here is my  function:

```
operator  infix fun  List<Teacher>.get(int: Int): Teacher {
    var t = Teacher()
    t.name = "asd"
    return t ;
}
```

and my usage:

```
b[0].teachers[1].name
```

tip: b is an object that has List< Teacher > property

and the error`Empty list doesn't contain element at index 1.`

why this override operator function  doesn't work?

Comment: You can't overshadow a method with an extension

Answer (score 8):

In Kotlin, you cannot shadow a member function with an extension. A **member always wins** in the call resolution. So, you basically cannot call an extension with a signature same to that of a member function, that is present in the type that was declared or inferred for the expression.

```
class C {
    fun foo() { println("member") }
}

fun C.foo() { println("extension") }

C().foo() // prints "member"
```

In your case, the member function is [`abstract operator fun get(index: Int): E`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/get.html) defined in `kotlin.collections.List`.

See the language reference: [Extensions are resolved **statically**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extensions-are-resolved-statically)

Answer (score 0):

As voddan mentions in the comment, you can't overshadow a method with an extension. However, there is a way to get around this with some polymorphism. I don't think I would recommend doing this in your case, but I guess it shows off a cool Kotlin feature.

If `b[0]` returns an object of type `B`, you could do this in that class:

```
data class B(private val _teachers: List<Teacher> = emptyList()) {
    private class Teachers(private val list: List<Teacher>) : List<Teacher> by list {
        override operator fun get(int: Int): Teacher {
            var t = Teacher() 
            t.name = "asd"
            return t ;
        }
    }

    val teachers: List<Teacher> = Teachers(_teachers)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(B().teachers[0].name) // Prints "asd"
}
```

When I override the `get`-function it will affect everyone that uses the `B` class, not just where you would import the extension-function.

Note that I am delegating all other method-calls on the `Teachers`-class through to the underlying list.