# Overload equals of BigDecimal in Kotlin

Tags: overloading, kotlin, equals

In a Kotlin file I try to overload the *equals* method of the *BigDecimal* class. I have the following piece of code for that:

```
fun BigDecimal.equals(n: Any?): Boolean = n is Int && this.compareTo(BigDecimal(n)) == 0
```

The problem is that this function does not get called by *n.equals(1)* where *n* is of type BigDecimal.
What's the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please note that this is NOT `overriding`, but `overshadowing`

Comment: Thanks for that tiny but important difference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not *override* or shadow functions of classes with extension functions. See the answer to a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44327728/4465208).

Comment: To summarize that means that with an extension function one cannot override the _equals_ operator?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html):

> If a class has a member function, and an extension function is defined which has the same receiver type, the same name and is applicable to given arguments, the member always wins.

Comment: Cool that it even compiles

Comment: Yes, but it shows a hint that the extension function is never used.

Answer (score 0):

Use infix extension functions like `a eq b`  / `a notEq b`:

```
internal infix fun BigDecimal.eq(other: BigDecimal): Boolean = this.compareTo(other) == 0
internal infix fun BigDecimal.eq(other: Int): Boolean = this.compareTo(other.toBigDecimal()) == 0
internal infix fun BigDecimal.notEq(other: BigDecimal): Boolean = !(this eq other)
internal infix fun BigDecimal.notEq(other: Int): Boolean = !(this eq other)
```